# How does the inner loop append on each iteration?

Tags: python, function, loops, recursion, nested

```
def per1(seq):
    if not seq:
        return [seq]
    else:
        res=[]
        for i in range(len(seq)):
            rest=seq[:i]+seq[i+1:]
            for x in per1(rest):
                 res.append(seq[i:i+1]+x)

        return res

print(per1('abc'))
```

The function is to print a permuted list of sequence but I am not sure how the inner for loop is working. I have tried to use `trace()` to see how the control is moving thru the loop but I couldn't figure how the loop is working the second time. The first time, `' rest '` value is `'bc','c'`.

Comment: Write down the variables on a piece of paper, then pretend you're the computer executing each statement.

Comment: what kind of IDE you using? try to utilize breakpoint and print statement. it is great for debugging and understanding iteration

Comment: FYI, `seq[:i]+seq[i+1:]` is just the string with `seq[i]` removed, and `seq[i:i+1]` is the same as `seq[i]`.

Comment: `seq[i:i+1]` is the same as `[seq[i]]`.

Answer (score 0):

Each time through the `for i` loop, `rest` is set to the input string with one character removed. The first time it has the first character removed, the second time it has the second character removed, etc. `seq[:i]` is every character before `i`, and `seq[i+1:]` is every character after `i`.

Then it calls itself recursively on `rest`. This returns all the permutations of that shorter string. So when `rest` is `"bc"`, this returns `["bc", "cb"]`. The `for x` loop iterates through this list, and concatenates each one to `seq[i:i+1]` (which is the character that was removed when creating `rest`), and appends this to `res`.

So the first iteration of the main loop sets `rest` to `"bc"`, then appends `"abc"` and `"acb"` to `res`.

The second iteration does the same thing, with `rest` set to `"ac"`, and `seq[i:i+1]` being the missing character `"b"`, so it appends `"bac"` and `"bca"` to `res`.

The third iteration is similar, with `rest` set to `"ab"`, so it appends `"cab"` and `"cba"` to `res`.

The special situation is the base case of the recursion. If the input string is empty, we just return a list with that empty string -- an empty string has trivial permutations. When the caller does its `for x` loop, it will simply concatenate this empty string onto the current letter. This case is needed to prevent infinite recursion. You could also make the case where `len(seq) == 1` the base case, since the permutations of a single letter is also trivial.